# grep the last match of an occurence with the nlines after that in a file bash

Tags: bash

may I ask how to grep the last match of an occurence with the nlines after that in a file bash? The file looks like in the following,

```
it is Starting 
line1
line2
ERROR
line3
line4
line5
ERROR
line6
line7
line8
WARNING
line9
ERROR
line10
line11
```

I want to grep the last "WARNING" with the two lines after that. The outcome should be

```
WARNING
line9
ERROR
```

I know `grep -A2 "WARNING"` can help all the `WARNINGS` with the two lines after, but how to do that for the last occurence then?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tac` to reverse the order of the lines in the file, `grep` with options `-m1` for maximum 1 match, and `-B2` for 2 lines preceding the match (preceding because the lines are in *reverse* order), followed by another `tac` to put the lines in the original order:

```
tac in_file | grep -m1 -B2 WARNING | tac
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post. This is much faster than [the preexisting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65332960/14122) when the input file is huge, since `tac` seeks directly to the end of the file and works backwards (so when a match is near the end, we avoid any need to read from the front).